# NullPointerException en lista doblemente enlazada

Tags: java, lista, nodos

Estoy utilizando lista doblemente enlazadas y me sale este error:

[image: me sale este error]

Les muestro a continuación mis clases, he intentado de todo y nada que me deja de salir.

```
public class Nodo {
    public Nodo ant;
    public int id;
    public String nombre;
    public String genero;
    public String eCivil;
    public double salario;
    public int tiempoServicio;
    public Nodo sig;
    
    
    
    public Nodo() {
        ant = null;
        sig = null;
        
    }

    public Nodo(Nodo dato) {
        id = dato.id;
        nombre = dato.nombre;
        genero = dato.genero;
        eCivil = dato.eCivil;
        salario = dato.salario;
        tiempoServicio = dato.tiempoServicio;
        
    }
}
```

```
public class Lista {

    private Nodo L;

    public Lista() {
        L = null;
    }
    
    public void imprimir() {
        Nodo p = L;
        int i = 1;
        if (L!= null) {
            
            do {
                System.out.println("ID: " + p.id + "| Nombre: " + p.nombre + "|  Genero: " + p.genero + "| Estado Civil: " + p.eCivil + "| Salario: " + p.salario + "| Tiempo de Servicio: " + p.tiempoServicio);
                i++;
                p = p.sig;
            } while (p != L);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lista Vacia");
        }

    }
    
    public void insertarInicio(Nodo dato) {
        Nodo X = new Nodo(dato);
        if (L != null) {
            X.sig = L;
            X.ant = L.ant;
            L.ant.sig = X;
            L.ant = X;
        }
        L = X;
    }

    public void insertarFinal(Nodo dato) {

        Nodo X = new Nodo(dato);
        if (L != null) {
            X.sig = L;
            X.ant = L.ant;
            (L.ant).sig = X;
            L.ant = X;

        } else {
            L = X;
        }

    }

    public Nodo insertarAntes(Nodo dato, int ref) {
        Nodo q = Buscar(ref);
        if (q != null) {
            if (q == L) {
                insertarInicio(dato);
            } else {
                Nodo X = new Nodo(dato);
                X.sig = q;
                X.ant = q.ant;
                q.ant.sig = X;
                q.ant = X;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Dato ref no encontrado");
        }
        return null;

    }

    public Nodo insertarDespues(Nodo dato, int ref) {
        Nodo q = Buscar(ref);
        if (q != null) {
            if (q.sig == null) {
                insertarFinal(dato);
            } else {
                Nodo X = new Nodo(dato);
                X.sig = q.sig;
                X.ant = q;
                q.sig.ant = X;
                q.sig = X;

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Dato ref no encontrado");
        }
        return null;

    }

     public Nodo BuscarID(int ref) {
        Nodo p = L;
        if (L != null) {
            do {
                if (p.id == ref) {
                    System.out.println("ID: " + p.id + "| Nombre: " + p.nombre + "|  Genero: " + p.genero + "| Estado Civil: " + p.eCivil + "| Salario: " + p.salario + "| Tiempo de Servicio: " + p.tiempoServicio);
                }
                p = p.sig;

            } while ((p != L));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Lista Vacia");
        }
        return null;
    }
     
    public Nodo Buscar(int ref) {
        Nodo p = L;
        while (p != null) {
            if (p.id == ref) {
                return p;
            }
            p = p.sig;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public Nodo eliminar(int Dato) {
        Nodo X = Buscar(Dato);
        if (X != null) {
            if (X == L) {
                if (L.sig == L) {
                    L = null;
                } else {
                    L.ant.sig = L.sig;
                    L.sig.ant = L.ant;
                    L = L.sig;
                }
            } else {
                if (X.sig == L) {
                    X.sig.ant = L;
                    L.ant = X.ant;
                } else {
                    X.ant.sig = X.sig;
                    X.sig.ant = X.ant;
                }
            }
            X.ant = null;
            X.sig = null;
            System.out.println("Elemento Eliminado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Dato no existe");
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

```
public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Nodo dato;
    public Lista listaCircularEmpleados;

    public Inicio() {
    initComponents();
    listaCircularEmpleados = new Lista();
    dato = new Nodo();
    }

     public void nuevo() {
      txtID.setText("");
      txtNombre.setText("");
      txtGenero.setText("");
      txtSalario.setText("");
      txtMensaje.setText("");
      cmdECivil.setSelectedIndex(0);
      txtID.requestFocus();
       }

    public void captura() {
     
         dato.id = Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText());
         dato.nombre = txtNombre.getText();
         dato.genero = txtGenero.getText();
         dato.eCivil = cmdECivil.getSelectedItem().toString();
         dato.salario = Integer.parseInt(txtSalario.getText());
         dato.tiempoServicio = (int) spinnerTServicio.getValue();
        
        
    
        }

     public void mensaje(String msg) {
         txtMensaje.setText(msg);
     }


                       

    private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        nuevo();
    }                                        

    private void btnInicioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        captura();
        listaCircularEmpleados.insertarInicio(dato);
        nuevo();
        mensaje("Registro Guardado al Inicio");
    }                                         

    private void btnImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        listaCircularEmpleados.imprimir();
    }                                           

    private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(1);
    }                                        

    private void btnFinalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        captura();
        listaCircularEmpleados.insertarFinal(dato);
        nuevo();
        mensaje("Registro Guardado al Final");
    }                                        

    private void btnDespuesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        captura();
        
        listaCircularEmpleados.insertarDespues(dato, ref);
        nuevo();
        mensaje("Registro Guardado al Inicio");
    }                                          

    private void btnAntesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    }                                        

    private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        
    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    }                                        

    private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        dato.id = Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText());
        
        cmdECivil.setSelectedIndex(0);
        txtID.requestFocus();
        mensaje("Eliminado");
        listaCircularEmpleados.eliminar(dato.id);

    }                                           

    private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

                       
}
```

Ojalá puedan ayudarme a solucionar este error.
Hay una `jframe` y dos clases una `Nodo` y otra `Lista`.
Intenté esto:

> "En resumen, para usar el constructor con parámetros en cualquier
> método que requiera crear un nuevo nodo, debes crear una instancia de
> la clase Nodo usando el constructor con parámetros, y pasando como
> argumento un objeto de tipo Nodo con los datos que deseas asignar al
> nuevo nodo."

Comment: Cuando tienes un único nodo, su anterior y siguiente los tienes a `null` (valor por defecto) con lo cual en tu bucle `while (p != L)` estás permitiendo acceder a un `null` como si fuese un nodo, o añades `while (p != L && p != null)` o cuando creas un nodo le asignas por defecto las referencias a `this` para que no tengas `null`s en medio de tu lista nunca.

Comment: no era eso solo tenia que agregar en el contructor .sig y .ant = this; igualmente gracias

Comment: *no era eso solo tenia que agregar en el contructor .sig y .ant = this;* -> Eso es precisamente lo que he dicho yo-> *"cuando creas un nodo le asignas por defecto las referencias a this"*

Comment: ósea si pero yo lo tenia en una clase me faltaba en otra